# Changing the sign of the moment map in the Seiberg Witten equations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gauge-theory, seiberg-witten

The Seiberg-Witten equations on a closed four manifold

$$
D_A \varphi = 0, F_A^+ = \mu(\varphi)
$$

are elliptic (up to gauge transformations), and so the equations

$$
D_A \varphi = 0, F_A^+ = -\mu(\varphi)
$$

are also elliptic up to gauge transformations. Is anything known about the moduli space of solutions to these equations? Maybe there is an easy argument that no solutions exist.

For this second set of equations the proof that the norm of the spinor is bounded doesn't carry across because of the change of sign, i.e. there is no a priori guarantee of compactness for the moduli space.

My motivation for thinking about this is that for the generalised SW equations, one considers the blown up equations after fixing $\|\varphi\| = 1$

$$
D_A\varphi = 0,  \varepsilon F_A^+ = \mu(\varphi)
$$

and so it might be worth considering the other set of equations with $\varepsilon < 0$.